# How to change the uri error message in codeigneiter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I was able to solve the problem of uri error in codeigniter as shown below:

```
 $config['permitted_uri_chars'] = 'a-z 0-9~%.:&_\-';
```

And now, I am looking where I could modify the error message
"The URI you submitted has disallowed characters" if it appears because I dont know where it comes from or how to do it. Also, I'd like to know how to display my own error 404
page when a uri contains disallowed characters. thanks

Answer (score 0):

please find the files under the errors folder and change the html content
error_404.php 
error_db.php 
error_general.phpetc

Comment: Thanks I got this in error_general.php . But, i could not modify the message caption without change the echo $message; . I need to modify the caption without deleting the $message.